# vim cut and paste history

Tags: vim

When I'm 'cutting' in vim, I believe there are registers that keep a history of all the recent things I've cut.  How do I access those registers?

For example, let's say I cut each one of these words consecutively

- 'Hello'
- 'World'
- 'And'
- 'Vim'

Note that I'm not actually saving these edits into particular registers, I'm just using 'd' four times consecutively.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

The

```
:help registers
```

command reveals that there are 10 numbered registers (`"0` to `"9`).

Register `"0` is the most recent thing *yanked*; register `"1` has the most recent *deleted* text, register `"2` the previous deletion, `"3` has the deletion before that, and so on.

If you delete each line in turn, registers `"1`, `"2`, `"3` and `"4` will contain "Vim", "And", "World" & "Hello", respectively.

You can verify this by using the `:reg` (or `:registers`) command:

```
:reg
""   Vim^J
"1   Vim^J
"2   And^J
"3   World^J
"4   Hello^J
```

So after deleting the four lines one at a time, you could recover the 2nd line ("World") with

```
"3p
```

because it's the third most recent deletion.

Comment: This is perfect; however, what I want the most recent 'yanked' text?

Comment: So you would use: p (which means the same as "0p)

Comment: Also pay attention to the special registers, especially "*" and "+", when you read `:help registers`. _Very_ useful.

Comment: Gods, you learn something new every day as a vimmer. It's great. Thanks, @njd.

Comment: This answer leaves out an important detail: Only deletions of one line or more are stored in the history this way. If you delete the words in the way that OP described in the question (using `d` four times, instead of `dd`) then all but the last deleted one are lost.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to njd's answer, this can be simplified with the [YankRing](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1234) plugin.  As well as making it easier to browse the previous yanks, you can configure some keys to allow you to pop previous yanks off the 'stack'.  This allows you to do:

```
yy    " Copy first line
yy    " Copy second line
yy    " Copy third line
yy    " Copy fourth line
" Assumes you've mapped ,p to be the pop command: choose your preferred key or key-combination
,p    " Paste fourth line and pop it off the Yank Ring
,p    " Paste third line and pop it off the Yank Ring
,p    " Paste second line and pop it off the Yank Ring
,p    " Paste first line and pop it off the Yank Ring
```

Comment: Could you add how to map `,p` to pop the previous yank?

Comment: To **pop** the last fews deletions in order: `"1p....`